# Question got roomba'd, would it be possible to undelete it?

Tags: support, status-completed, deleted-questions

Just a few moments ago, I realized that one of my questions ([Relation between core mass and red giant mass?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40700/31410)) got deleted by Community for inactivity. Would it be possible to undelete it so I can place a bounty on it?

Comment: Done! Undeleted!